# js : not running function for each div onload

Tags: javascript

```
<div onload="mkid(4)" id='bxltr'></div>
<div onload="mkid(9)" id='bxltr'></div>
<div onload="mkid(7)" id='bxltr'></div>

<script>
function mkid(itg){
    nitg=itg+455+367*674;
    document.getElementById('bxltr').innerHTML=nitg;
}
</script>
```

I want to get value from specific div's onload function and then return that value to its specified div, but after running this script nothing is displayed on page

Comment: ids must be unique, change them, if you want to group them, you can use class="bxltr" instead of id="bxltr"

Comment: Ids should **NOT** be repeated by convention.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot use onload on a div element. It will not work
2. Id's must be unique

Try this solution, it's working as you wanted

```js
function mkid(){
    
   var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('bxltr');
  
  for(var i = 0; i< elements.length; i++) {
    var nitg = Number(elements[i].getAttribute("data-count")) +455+367*674;
    elements[i].innerHTML = nitg;
  }
}

window.onload = mkid;
```

```html
<div data-count="4" class='bxltr'></div>
<div data-count="9" class='bxltr'></div>
<div data-count="7" class='bxltr'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes):

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('.bxltr')
  .forEach(el => el.innerHTML = el.dataset.mk + 455 + 367 * 674);
```

```html
<div data-mk="4" class="bxltr"></div>
<div data-mk="9" class="bxltr"></div>
<div data-mk="7" class="bxltr"></div>
```